# I would insert two buttons in the navigation bar using Ionic Framework

Tags: button, uinavigationcontroller, icons, uinavigationbar, ionic-framework

I use Ionic Framework and I would insert two buttons in the navigation bar only this page.

```
<ion-view title="{{title}}"> 
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <a style="color: white;" class="button button-icon icon ion-folder" 
        ng-click="clickCreaElencoSpese()" ng-href="#/creaNotaSpese"></a> 
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

I would like to get to get two icons in the image below close as two different functions.
How can I?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add another button.

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <a style="color: white;" class="button button-icon icon ion-trash-a"></a> 
    <a style="color: white;" class="button button-icon icon ion-folder" ng-click="clickCreaElencoSpese()" ng-href="#/creaNotaSpese"></a> 
</ion-nav-buttons>
```